# Angularjs how to loads required js files home page index.html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-resource

We have angularjs app with lot of js getting loaded during the initial page load. Which are not required as part of home page.  How we can void these. Is requieedjs solve this. How and when other js files get loads.

Comment: You can use RequireJS for this.

Answer (score 1):

requirejs can be troublesome to use with angular

use following:
https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs